# How to change default redis configuration on Lumen Framework?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm using Lumen Framework for my new application. Previously, I have used Laravel Framework in my other projects.

In laravel projects based on laravel that I have developed I could set configuration of Redis on the file located in "config/database.php". Now that I'm using Lumen I can't find that file.

I would like to set redis database name, host, port, etc in my configuration file.

this is my current configuration in the file ".env"

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=
APP_TIMEZONE=UTC

DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=database_development
DB_USERNAME=admin
DB_PASSWORD=admin

CACHE_DRIVER=redis
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

I hope your help. Thanks

Comment: Not sure about Lumen but in Laravel the redis configuration is read from `database.php` which reads things like `REDIS_HOST` etc from the .env

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change these settings in `config/database.php`.

This is my default:

```
'redis' => [

    'cluster' => false,

    'default' => [
        'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
        'port'     => 6379,
        'database' => 0,
    ],

],
```

If you wanted to have these settings in your `.env` file, you can change the `config/database.php` file to something like:

```
'redis' => [

    'cluster' => false,

    'default' => [
        'host'     => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port'     => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => env('REDIS_DATABASE', 0),
    ],

],
```

And your `.env` file add:

```
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PORT=6379
REDIS_DATABASE=0
```

And don't forget to `php artisan config:clear` to clear config cache.

Hope this helps.

Comment: A lot of thanks. 
I just added:

    REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
    REDIS_PORT=6379
    REDIS_DATABASE=0

that works fine